# Get rotation/direction of moving object in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, rotation, angle, direction

I've built a small simple game that launches objects with certain angle and force to try and calculate roughly and knock down stuff. The mechanics are like angry birds and similar games.

There is a negative force that works against the X (friction and random wind), and gravity and works against my Y.

So, this works fine, but I'd like my projectile (the object I'm throwing) to be pointing always towards the direction it's moving. I'm not quite sure of what formula I can use for this.

Can anyone help please? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar with a vector (arrow) angle, using simple trigonometry. 
arrowEnd and arrowStart are just child movieclips I've placed graphically inside the object itself.

```
        public function getAngle():Number
    {
        var end=arrowEnd.getEndPoint();
        var start=arrowStart.getStartPoint();
        var angle = Math.atan((end.y - start.y) / (end.x - start.x));
        var angleInDegrees = angle * 180/Math.PI;
        return(angleInDegrees);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's almost working but not exactly pointing towards the direction its moving... I'm missing something maybe?

Comment: Ok I got it working, I adapted your example to my code and its fine. Thanks!